# Product rule for gradient of cross product

Tags: differential-geometry, cross-product

The book I am reading gives a list of product rules, among them the following:

$$\nabla \cdot (v\times w) =(\nabla \cdot v) w-v\nabla \cdot w.$$

However, the left-hand side is a number whereas the right-hand side is a vector.

So clearly, something is wrong, maybe a dot should be replaced by a cross product, but I have not found a similar correct expression.

> What is the formula that the authors tried to write?

Comment: The expression you write cannot be correct because a dot product (LHS) gives a scalar whereas scalar multipication of a vector (RHS) gives a vector. Incidentally, if you want to work this out carefully, you might look at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/809689/36530 where a more difficult, but related, identity is derived.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only product rule that I know for this situation is
$$
\nabla\cdot(v\times w)=w\cdot(\nabla\times v)-v\cdot(\nabla\times w).
$$